# iOS Safari position:fixed doesn't work at all

Tags: ios, css, safari, position, fixed

position:fixed doesn't work on mobile safari browser. I've tried two devices, iPhone7 and 5s with latest Safari versions. I'm losing my mind. No internet trick I've already found could help me. I found one site where my iPhone actually showed me fixed navigation bar. But when I copied that site's source code into my code, my iphone refused to show navbar as fixed element.

```
.fixed {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  z-index:1;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Also, these devices don't support any kind of scroll detection, neither `window.pageYOffset` nor `window.parent.pageYOffset` nor `document.documentElement.scrollTop`. All shows 0.
Please, help me. I cant stand this anymore

Comment: Can you show us the full site perhaps, if possible?

Comment: Are you talking about the site where my iPhone shows position:fixed correctly? If it is so, here is the link https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryw3css_templates_apartment_rental.htm

Comment: No, where it shows it incorrectly

Comment: https://codepen.io/killkock/full/eRKJxe/. Here. But it shows incorrectly every time I'm using just a simple position:fixed. I know there must be some kind of a trick to make it be fixed, but i cant find it

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following CSS

```
nav{
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

If that doesn't work, try this instead

```
nav{
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Please let me know if it helps

Comment: Hello, Currently those 2 doesnt work on mine, Do you have any other solutions for position:fixed images that doesnt show on older version of safari?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `position:fixed` happened because my code was run in Codepen. Everything works fine